# Boombox extending power autonomy

Tags: audio

Hi Im building a boombox and I am looking for ways to extend the power autonomy.

I am using this stereo([https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0091V0A9U/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1514153185&sr=8-3&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=pioneer+stereo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0091V0A9U)) and these speakers([https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0081SRIFS/ref=mp_s_a_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1514153301&sr=8-6&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=pioneer+speaker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0081SRIFS)).

I will put the boombox in the back seats of my car and it will be powered by 2 12v batteries(not the main car battery).

I assume that the specification of 200w is per 1 speaker, and 50 watts of the stereo is per 1 channel(so i doubled both because Im using 2 speakers and 2 channels)

I used I=W/V ---->I=[(200×2)+(50x2)]/12volts--->I=41.7 Amps

I got 2 12v 7ah lead acids so (7x2)/41.7=0.33 or 20 mins of playing the boombox at full blast. My questions are the following:

-Are my calculations wrong? If not, how is it possible that a little boombox uses so much power?

-How can I make the boombox play for longer? Add batteries? Lower volume? (I am trying to avoid using the main car battery). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your calculation is wrong. The power output will be what the head unit outputs, which is 100W for two channels. The speaker rating only shows what it is capable of handling and should not be used in your calculation. Note that input power will be slightly higher than output power.

Comment: Awesome thank you, so am I wasting my money getting speakers rated at 200w when the head unit can only output 100w?

Comment: Not necessarily, but maybe. I haven't examined the specs, but your speakers should be able to handle both peak power and RMS power. Hopefully the 50W output per channel is RMS. If not, the good news is you can use even smaller batteries because you should use the RMS power in your calculations. If it is RMS, then peak power will be higher. I'd keep some leeway in the speaker's capabilities unless you can get slightly smaller ones for much cheaper, which is unlikely.

Comment: you can blow out a 200W speaker with a 50W amplifier if you overdrive the amp to the point where it starts clipping. the energy in the resulting square wave can be enough to destroy the speaker.